# Adding the Jquery tab panel to a specific div

Tags: jquery, tabs, jquery-ui-tabs, jquery-tabs, tabpanel

I was sure there was an answer to this question already but I've spent several hours looking with no luck.

This is my basic setup.

```
<div id='container'>
  <ul id="tabs">
    <li>Tab 1</li>
    <li>Tab 2</li>
  </ul>
  <div id="panels">
    <div>panel 1</div>
    <div>panel 2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

When I dynamically add a new tab I would like the tab to appear inside the "panels" div like "panel 1" and "panel 2".

However, when I dynamically add "tab 3" (see below) "panel 3" is added below the panels tab not inside it.

```
<div id='container'>
      <ul id="tabs">
        <li>Tab 1</li>
        <li>Tab 2</li>

        <li>Tab 3</li>

      </ul>
      <div id="panels">
        <div>panel 1</div>
        <div>panel 2</div>
      </div>

      <div>panel 3</div>

    </div>
```

How can I add my new "panel 3" panel to the "panels" div?

Comment: how are you adding the tab and the panel?

Comment: $("#container").tabs( 'add', '#tabs-3', 'Tab 3' );

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
$('#panel3').appendTo('#panels');
```

This will **move** `panel3` inside `panels`

Comment: The panel is dynamically created when I create the new tab. Are you suggesting appending the newly created "<div>panel 3</div>" to the end of the panels tab? Is this best practice?

Comment: Generally, it's not a good practice to change plugin-generated markup structure. I was suggesting it beacause you already did with panel 1 and panel 2. It will work, however avoid doing such things as possible.

Comment: Just to comment, when i used the tabs plugin for the first time, i also thought there should be a panels container. I don't know why they didn't put one.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#panels").append("<div> panel3</div>");
```